# JToolbar::save() redirection

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm going through the Joomla 2.5 tutorial to build a custom component. Now I'm facing an issue on the redirection after using `JToolbar::save()` or `JToolBarHelper::cancel` for that matter. By default Joomla wants to redirect to the default layout (from the edit layout). However I don't want it to do that. I want it to redirect back to another view. In Joomla 1.5 I would have done this through adding the function into the controller - something like

```
function cancel()
{
    //redirects user back to blog homepage with Cancellation Message
    $msg = JText::_( 'COM_BLOG_POST_CANCELLED' );
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_jjblog&view=jjblog', $msg );
}
```

Now that works beautifully for the cancel function, however for save this is a much more complex thing. If I want to overwrite the url do I have to redirect the controller to the model and then write in all the code for the model interaction? Because that seems slightly excessive just for a url redirection like you would in Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have added the save toolbar code with the proper controller name like this

1. `JToolBarHelper::save('controllerName.save');`
2. Create a save function in appropriate controller.
3. Add the task in the form
4. Finnally make sure you have added form action withthe corresponding component name.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this-

In the controller firstly you call the parent save function than redirect to url.

```
function save(){
 parent::save();        
 $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_mycomponent');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK it didn't need to `$this->setRedirect` at all. Just needed me to change the value to

```
protected $view_list = 'jjBlog';
```

which then sets the redirects of everything back to that list view.

Source link for this is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-cms/IN_4eIetdaQ/gkmyAGCIBBsJ).

Thanks for all the responses though!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
global $mainframe;
$mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_user&task=activate&activation=".$activation);
```

If you are overriding joomla's default save function in your custom component like

```
function save( $task = 'CustomSave', $alt = 'Save' ) // or even same name Save
```

Inside your controller you can use the CustomSave as the task and use $mainframe for redirect.

```
or
$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_user&task=activate&activation=".$activation);
```

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

view.html.php

```
protected function addToolbar ()
    {
        JRequest::setVar ('hidemainmenu', false);
        JToolBarHelper::title (JText::_ ('Configuration'), 'configuration.gif');
        JToolBarHelper::save($task = 'save', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');

    }
```

controller.php

```
public function save()
    {  
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $mainframe->enqueueMessage (JText::_ ('COM_SOCIALLOGIN_SETTING_SAVED'));    
        $this->setRedirect (JRoute::_ ('index.php', false));
    }
```